# Why haven't Saturn's rings coalesced into moons/satellites?

Tags: moons, saturn

The rings of Saturn are made up of tiny particles/rocks/ice that all orbit Saturn.  Each individual particle is bound to its orbit because of Saturn's gravity, but each particle also pulls on all of its neighbor particles as well.  Shouldn't Saturn's rings have collapsed into moons or satellites by now?  What is keeping the rings rings and not letting them turn into moons/satellites?

Comment: I think this question would be a better fit for the astronomy SE site.

Comment: Although the line is not always clear, in this case for sure this is a great question for [Astronomy SE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/) (if it hasn't been answered there already) and probably off-topic here. I don't see any Space *Exploration* aspects. I'd recommend you just delete here and then join Astronomy SE and post it there. It's a great site and you are obviously interested in astronomy.

Comment: Asked (and answered) a long time ago at physics SE: [Why Aren't Saturn's Rings Clumping into Moons?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26643/why-arent-saturns-rings-clumping-into-moons)

Comment: This also falls under Space Exploration.  If this question https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2259/why-are-the-rings-of-saturn-so-much-brighter-than-the-other-planets?rq=1 is legitimate on this site, then so is mine.

Comment: @rickestrick: the other question should have been marked as off topic as well, but for some reason it wasn’t and at this point in time (after the op accepts an answer) it can’t be changed.

Comment: @RickestRick It turns out the question from 2013 you've linked to was asked *only about two weeks after the first question ever in Astronomy SE was asked!* On-topicness is an evolving thing, and having a question closed might smart a bit the first time, but it's really not a bad thing at all and does not reflect upon the question itself.

Comment: Roll tide roll, maybe?